# Move a set of git commits to HEAD

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a fork on which there are a handful of commits spread out over a couple of years.

I want to consolidate them all on the HEAD. This is so that merging from upstream is done as a rebase and the commits will stay at HEAD.

Im trying to avoid having these commits get lost in history and accidentally wiped on an upstream merge.

I think I coul to an interactive rebase but seems tedious given these few commits are spread out over hundreds of upstream commits in the past two years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try cherry-picking those commits to their own separate branch, and always rebase from that branch.